# extract-text-webpack-plugin difficulties getting .css file output

Tags: angularjs, webpack

I am using AngularClass' angular seed. I have 1 application.scss file that I am trying to get exported into a css file through webpack and the extract-text-webpack plugin. I am following the webpack stylesheets page found here: http://webpack.github.io/docs/stylesheets.html#separate-css-bundle

but I can't seem to get my .css file to appear in my /dist folder after running webpack.

Does anyone have any ideas?

I have included my webpack config file below.

```js
/**
 * @author: @AngularClass
 */

const webpack = require('webpack');
const helpers = require('./helpers');

/*
 * Webpack Plugins
 */
// problem with copy-webpack-plugin
var CopyWebpackPlugin = (CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin'), CopyWebpackPlugin.default || CopyWebpackPlugin);
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ForkCheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').ForkCheckerPlugin;
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
/*
 * Webpack Constants
 */
const METADATA = {
  title: 'Angular2 Webpack Starter by @gdi2290 from @AngularClass',
  baseUrl: '/'
};

/*
 * Webpack configuration
 *
 * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#cli
 */
module.exports = {

  /*
   * Static metadata for index.html
   *
   * See: (custom attribute)
   */
  metadata: METADATA,

  /*
   * Cache generated modules and chunks to improve performance for multiple incremental builds.
   * This is enabled by default in watch mode.
   * You can pass false to disable it.
   *
   * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#cache
   * cache: false,
   *
   * The entry point for the bundle
   * Our Angular.js app
   *
   * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#entry
   */
  entry: {

    'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
    'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
    'main': './src/main.browser.ts'

  },
   output:{
  path: helpers.root('dist'),
  filename: '[name].bundle.js',
  sourceMapFilename: '[name].map'
  
   },
  /*
   * Options affecting the resolving of modules.
   *
   * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve
   */
  resolve: {

    /*
     * An array of extensions that should be used to resolve modules.
     *
     * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-extensions
     */
    extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js'],

    // Make sure root is src
    root: helpers.root('src'),

    // remove other default values
    modulesDirectories: ['node_modules'],

    alias: {
      'angular2/core': helpers.root('node_modules/@angular/core/index.js'),
      'angular2/testing': helpers.root('node_modules/@angular/core/testing.js'),
      '@angular/testing': helpers.root('node_modules/@angular/core/testing.js'),
      'angular2/platform/browser': helpers.root('node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/index.js'),
      'angular2/router': helpers.root('node_modules/@angular/router-deprecated/index.js'),
      'angular2/http': helpers.root('node_modules/@angular/http/index.js'),
      'angular2/http/testing': helpers.root('node_modules/@angular/http/testing.js')
    },

  },

  /*
   * Options affecting the normal modules.
   *
   * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module
   */
  module: {

    /*
     * An array of applied pre and post loaders.
     *
     * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module-preloaders-module-postloaders
     */
    preLoaders: [

      /*
       * Tslint loader support for *.ts files
       *
       * See: https://github.com/wbuchwalter/tslint-loader
       */
       // { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'tslint-loader', exclude: [ helpers.root('node_modules') ] },

      /*
       * Source map loader support for *.js files
       * Extracts SourceMaps for source files that as added as sourceMappingURL comment.
       *
       * See: https://github.com/webpack/source-map-loader
       */
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'source-map-loader',
        exclude: [
          // these packages have problems with their sourcemaps
          helpers.root('node_modules/rxjs'),
          helpers.root('node_modules/@angular2-material'),
          helpers.root('node_modules/@angular'),
        ]
      }

    ],

    /*
     * An array of automatically applied loaders.
     *
     * IMPORTANT: The loaders here are resolved relative to the resource which they are applied to.
     * This means they are not resolved relative to the configuration file.
     *
     * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module-loaders
     */
    loaders: [

      /*
       * Typescript loader support for .ts and Angular 2 async routes via .async.ts
       *
       * See: https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader
       */
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
        exclude: [/\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/]
      },

      /*
       * Json loader support for *.json files.
       *
       * See: https://github.com/webpack/json-loader
       */
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json-loader'
      },
   {
    test: /\.(png|jpg)$/, 
    loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192'
   },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader!sass-loader')
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader')
      },
   { test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
      { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "file-loader" },
      /* Raw loader support for *.html
       * Returns file content as string
       *
       * See: https://github.com/webpack/raw-loader
       */
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'raw-loader',
        exclude: [helpers.root('src/index.html')]
      }

    ]

  },

  /*
   * Add additional plugins to the compiler.
   *
   * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#plugins
   */
  plugins: [
  new ExtractTextPlugin("[name].css"),
 
    /*
     * Plugin: ForkCheckerPlugin
     * Description: Do type checking in a separate process, so webpack don't need to wait.
     *
     * See: https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader#forkchecker-boolean-defaultfalse
     */
    new ForkCheckerPlugin(),

    /*
     * Plugin: OccurenceOrderPlugin
     * Description: Varies the distribution of the ids to get the smallest id length
     * for often used ids.
     *
     * See: https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#occurrenceorderplugin
     * See: https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/optimization#minimize
     */
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(true),

    /*
     * Plugin: CommonsChunkPlugin
     * Description: Shares common code between the pages.
     * It identifies common modules and put them into a commons chunk.
     *
     * See: https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#commonschunkplugin
     * See: https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/optimization#multi-page-app
     */
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: ['polyfills', 'vendor'].reverse()
    }),

    /*
     * Plugin: CopyWebpackPlugin
     * Description: Copy files and directories in webpack.
     *
     * Copies project static assets.
     *
     * See: https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-webpack-plugin
    
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
      from: 'src/assets',
      to: 'assets'
    }]),
  */


    /*
     * Plugin: HtmlWebpackPlugin
     * Description: Simplifies creation of HTML files to serve your webpack bundles.
     * This is especially useful for webpack bundles that include a hash in the filename
     * which changes every compilation.
     *
     * See: https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
     */
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.html',
      chunksSortMode: 'dependency'
    })

  ],

  /*
   * Include polyfills or mocks for various node stuff
   * Description: Node configuration
   *
   * See: https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#node
   */
  node: {
    global: 'window',
    crypto: 'empty',
    module: false,
    clearImmediate: false,
    setImmediate: false
  }

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my own issue. I didn't realize that I needed to include the source path of my scss file since it was several folders deep so here is what I added to my webpack.config.js

```
path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'assets', 'sass', 'application.scss')
```

in the entry section.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using style!css!sass loaders to bundle my css and scss files. You could try installing this loaders from NPM, in case you already didn't, and removing ExtractTextPlugin. Your webpack.config.js should look like this:

```
/**
 * @author: @AngularClass
 */

const webpack = require('webpack');
const helpers = require('./helpers');

/*
 * Webpack Plugins
 */
// problem with copy-webpack-plugin
var CopyWebpackPlugin = (CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin'), CopyWebpackPlugin.default || CopyWebpackPlugin);
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ForkCheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').ForkCheckerPlugin;

/*
 * Webpack Constants
 */
const METADATA = {
  title: 'Angular2 Webpack Starter by @gdi2290 from @AngularClass',
  baseUrl: '/'
};

/*
 * Webpack configuration
 *
 * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#cli
 */
module.exports = {

  /*
   * Static metadata for index.html
   *
   * See: (custom attribute)
   */
  metadata: METADATA,

  /*
   * Cache generated modules and chunks to improve performance for multiple incremental builds.
   * This is enabled by default in watch mode.
   * You can pass false to disable it.
   *
   * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#cache
   * cache: false,
   *
   * The entry point for the bundle
   * Our Angular.js app
   *
   * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#entry
   */
  entry: {

    'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
    'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
    'main': './src/main.browser.ts'

  },
   output:{
     path: helpers.root('dist'),
     filename: '[name].bundle.js',
     sourceMapFilename: '[name].map'

   },
  /*
   * Options affecting the resolving of modules.
   *
   * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve
   */
  resolve: {

    /*
     * An array of extensions that should be used to resolve modules.
     *
     * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-extensions
     */
    extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js'],

    // Make sure root is src
    root: helpers.root('src'),

    // remove other default values
    modulesDirectories: ['node_modules'],

    alias: {
      'angular2/core': helpers.root('node_modules/@angular/core/index.js'),
      'angular2/testing': helpers.root('node_modules/@angular/core/testing.js'),
      '@angular/testing': helpers.root('node_modules/@angular/core/testing.js'),
      'angular2/platform/browser': helpers.root('node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/index.js'),
      'angular2/router': helpers.root('node_modules/@angular/router-deprecated/index.js'),
      'angular2/http': helpers.root('node_modules/@angular/http/index.js'),
      'angular2/http/testing': helpers.root('node_modules/@angular/http/testing.js')
    },

  },

  /*
   * Options affecting the normal modules.
   *
   * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module
   */
  module: {

    /*
     * An array of applied pre and post loaders.
     *
     * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module-preloaders-module-postloaders
     */
    preLoaders: [

      /*
       * Tslint loader support for *.ts files
       *
       * See: https://github.com/wbuchwalter/tslint-loader
       */
       // { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'tslint-loader', exclude: [ helpers.root('node_modules') ] },

      /*
       * Source map loader support for *.js files
       * Extracts SourceMaps for source files that as added as sourceMappingURL comment.
       *
       * See: https://github.com/webpack/source-map-loader
       */
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'source-map-loader',
        exclude: [
          // these packages have problems with their sourcemaps
          helpers.root('node_modules/rxjs'),
          helpers.root('node_modules/@angular2-material'),
          helpers.root('node_modules/@angular'),
        ]
      }

    ],

    /*
     * An array of automatically applied loaders.
     *
     * IMPORTANT: The loaders here are resolved relative to the resource which they are applied to.
     * This means they are not resolved relative to the configuration file.
     *
     * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module-loaders
     */
    loaders: [

      /*
       * Typescript loader support for .ts and Angular 2 async routes via .async.ts
       *
       * See: https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader
       */
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
        exclude: [/\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/]
      },

      /*
       * Json loader support for *.json files.
       *
       * See: https://github.com/webpack/json-loader
       */
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg)$/, 
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192'
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: ExtractPlugin.extract('style', 'css!sass'),
      },
      { test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
      { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "file-loader" },
      /* Raw loader support for *.html
       * Returns file content as string
       *
       * See: https://github.com/webpack/raw-loader
       */
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'raw-loader',
        exclude: [helpers.root('src/index.html')]
      }

    ]

  },

  /*
   * Add additional plugins to the compiler.
   *
   * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#plugins
   */
  plugins: [
     /*Try using this*/
     new ExtractPlugin('main.css'),

     /*
     * Plugin: ForkCheckerPlugin
     * Description: Do type checking in a separate process, so webpack don't need to wait.
     *
     * See: https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader#forkchecker-boolean-defaultfalse
     */
    new ForkCheckerPlugin(),

    /*
     * Plugin: OccurenceOrderPlugin
     * Description: Varies the distribution of the ids to get the smallest id length
     * for often used ids.
     *
     * See: https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#occurrenceorderplugin
     * See: https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/optimization#minimize
     */
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(true),

    /*
     * Plugin: CommonsChunkPlugin
     * Description: Shares common code between the pages.
     * It identifies common modules and put them into a commons chunk.
     *
     * See: https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#commonschunkplugin
     * See: https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/optimization#multi-page-app
     */
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: ['polyfills', 'vendor'].reverse()
    }),

    /*
     * Plugin: CopyWebpackPlugin
     * Description: Copy files and directories in webpack.
     *
     * Copies project static assets.
     *
     * See: https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-webpack-plugin

    new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
      from: 'src/assets',
      to: 'assets'
    }]),
     */


    /*
     * Plugin: HtmlWebpackPlugin
     * Description: Simplifies creation of HTML files to serve your webpack bundles.
     * This is especially useful for webpack bundles that include a hash in the filename
     * which changes every compilation.
     *
     * See: https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
     */
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.html',
      chunksSortMode: 'dependency'
    })

  ],

  /*
   * Include polyfills or mocks for various node stuff
   * Description: Node configuration
   *
   * See: https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#node
   */
  node: {
    global: 'window',
    crypto: 'empty',
    module: false,
    clearImmediate: false,
    setImmediate: false
  }

};
```

This should bundle the css to your main js file.

Comment: That's why I am using ExtractTextPlugin though, I don't want my css in my main.js file I want a separate application.css file.

Comment: I see. I edited my answer using extract with the config that works for me. Adding `new ExtractPlugin('main.css')` to your plugins section should extract your css to a main.css file. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: Thanks - see my answer above. I fixed my own problem and it wasn't related to the plugin. I didn't have the correct directory for my SASS file.